# How can I get the name of the current web app in Java EE?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

How can I get the name of the current web app in Java EE?

I'm quite comfortable with stand-alone Java, but Java EE is new to me. I'm writing some custom code to plug in to a third-party Java EE reporting package. I have multiple instances deployed on the same Tomcat server, so I have something like:

```
C:\
+-- tomcat6
    +-- webapps
        +-- app1
        +-- app2
```

So when the user goes to, let's say, http://example.com/app1/viewReport, I want to be able to get "app1". (And not by parsing the URL, preferrably.)

Also, if there was a way to get the root of app1 (in this example, C:\tomcat6\webapps\app1), that would be great too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Getting the "name"
   =====
   It's called the context path. If your code is running within the web app request context, you can get it by calling [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()).
2. Accessing the physical/real resource
   =====
   If you're trying to access the contents of a file/resource in your webapp, you're best of using one of:

- [`ServletContext#getResource(String)`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource(java.lang.String))
- [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

It is also possible get the physical path on disk of a file/resource, given the path relative to the web app, using [`ServletContext#getRealPath(String)`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)), but it's not reliable (doesn't always work if you deploy you webapp as a WAR, for instance).

3. Accessing class path resources
   =====
   Per your comment, you were trying to access a resource within the /WEB-INF/classes directory. Because WEB-INF/classes/* is where web application specific classes go, you can simply access it as if you were accessing any classpath resource in a Java SE application. Again, assuming your code runs within the context of the webapp, you can simply use the following:

- [Class#getResource(String)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))
- [Class#getResourceAsStream(String)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

In your case, you'd probably want to use the latter, and then load the Properties file via Properties#load(InputStream).

Something along the lines of:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reportCustom.properties"));
```

Comment: thanks for your help. what i'm trying to do is load a properties file in `webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/reportCustom.properties`. is this a simpler way to do it?  in the past, i got System.getProperty("myapp.root"), with a hardcoded string, which is a property from web.xml that gives the root path. But then I find that we need to support multiple instances on the same Tomcat, so I don't know what "myapp" will be called.

Comment: In your case, you can access reportCustom.properties as if it's simply in the classpath. I'll update my answer to include this shortly.

Answer (score 2):

> what i'm trying to do is load a properties file in webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/reportCustom.properties

Since the file is in the `classes` directory, you can load it using the [ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) (the usual Java mechanism for loading files on the classpath). It is probably best to use the [context ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader()).